# iOS- Image not showing up with custom cell (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, custom-cell

I'm attempting to use a custom cell class (customCell) to show images from my array in a cell. If I use the default cell (without 'as! customCell') the images show - so I can only assume it is something to do with my custom cell class (customCell)

**Here is my custom cell class code:**

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

var customImageView: UIImageView {
    let customImage = UIImageView()
    customImage.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage")
    return customImage
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(customImageView)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

**and my tableView code where I'm attempting to call the image (if it matters):**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)  as! customCell

    let array = displayArray[indexPath.section]

    cell.customImageView.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage")

    if let imageUrl = array.imageUrl {
        let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                 cell.customImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

            }
            }.resume()
    }

            return cell
}
```

Comment: You add customImageView to your cell, but you don't give it any size or positioning info. What is the frame of the image view after you've added it and set an image on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the frame of your `UIImageView`:

```
var customImageView: UIImageView {
    let customImage = UIImageView()
    customImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    customImage.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage")
    return customImage
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It does display the placeholder image now, but not the image from the array. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @JohnTucker Updated the answer. your `customImageView ` get resets to placeholder image every time you access it.

Comment: I removed it but then nothing shows at all. I have to assume its something to do with the custom cell because when I was using a default cell it was working. Any other thoughts? Thanks again for all your input.

Comment: @JohnTucker I think my answer might not be correct then. Can you un-accept it?